# How to create POST request using insertMany in nest js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

Here is my service.ts file:

```
    public async addVendorServicesSpecialPrice(data: any): Promise<any | Error> {
    try {

        let reqArray: any[] = [];
        data?.forEach((item: any) => {
            let reqObj = new vendorServiceSpecialPriceCollection({...item })
            if (Object.keys(reqObj).length > 0) {
                reqArray.push(reqObj);
            }
        })
        await vendorServiceSpecialPriceCollection.insertMany(reqArray);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('service error\n', e);
        throw e;
    }
};``
```

I am trying to create a post request using insertMany,But i'm getting this error that: data.forEach is not a function.I am using nest js,so any suggestion how to achive this...

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

`data:` any is not an array which you are receiving as a parameter. foreach and map works on array. That's why it's saying data.foreach() is not a function.